# how can i use drawerlayout in android 4.4 with Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR_OVERLAY

Tags: android, android-4.4-kitkat, drawerlayout

I want use android 4.4 new function,but i has some problem.when i use drawerlayout, i made actionbar with FEATURE_ACTION_BAR_OVERLAY.but it just one could fitsSystemWindows,does anyone who know this?`

```
<ScrollView
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:clipToPadding="true"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="ssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssdddddddddddddddddddd
        ssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssdddddddddddddddddddd
        ssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssdddddddddddddddddddd
        ssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssdddddddddddddddddddd
        ssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssdddddddddddddddddddd
        ssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssdddddddddddddddddddd
        ssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssdddddddddddddddddddd
        ssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssdddddddddddddddddddd
        ssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssdddddddddddddddddddd
        ssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssdddddddddddddddddddd
        ssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssdddddddddddddddddddd
        ssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssdddddddddddddddddddd
        ssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssdddddddddddddddddddd
        ssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssdddddddddddddddddddd
        ssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssdddddddddddddddddddd
        ssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssdddddddddddddddddddd"
        android:textSize="35sp" />
</ScrollView>

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/menulayout"
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:background="#33b5e5"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true" >

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="#777777" >
    </FrameLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

`